# What graphics card is suitable for my motherboard?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, motherboard, integrated-graphics

Following the title, can someone recommend a graphics card for my motherboard?

This is my motherboard: http://www.biostar-usa.com/mbdetails.asp?model=945GZ%20MICRO%20775%20SE

I don't want to use the integrated graphics card provided as it is very slow.

Comment: What kind of use are you looking to get out of this video card? Gaming? Regular browsing? etc?

Comment: casual gaming and regular browsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you looking for is the PCI-Ex16 slot on the motherboard.  That's what you should be looking for in type of graphics card.  [Here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007709%20600007852&IsNodeId=1&name=PCI%20Express%20x16) are a few from NewEgg.

A quick guide to selecting a gaming video card is looking at the memory of the card, and the gpu.  For example: a video card with only 128 Mb of ram on the card, will have to pull lots of memory from the system.  However a video card with 1 gig of ram or more will have to "borrow" less from the pc.  [Here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gtx-460-radeon-hd-5570-gaming,2697.html) is a good guide to buying a GPU for the best money from Tom's Hardware.

Comment: Thanks! I found my card!
http://www.chinavasion.com/product_info.php/pName/ati-radeon-hd4650-128mb-pci-express-x16-graphics-card/

(No I do not live in China)